# Getting an error inserting a user variable into a table with Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I've been trying to insert a new entry into a table, but I'm having problem inserting the current date. For context, I'm using Visual Studio with the Visual Basic language. The method that I have in the data access object is this one:

```
Public Function InsertPlayback(ByVal u As User, ByVal s As Song, plDate As Date) As Integer
    Return DBBroker.GetBroker.Change("INSERT INTO PLAYBACKS (user, song, plDate) VALUES ('" & u.Email & "', " & s.idSong & ", '" & Date.Today.ToString & "');")
End Function
```

And the error that I'm having is "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement". It is really weird, since I'm trying this same SQL sentence in Access where I have stored the database and it is giving me what it should without any errors. Does anyone know what is happening? Do I have to install or configure something?

### Solution

Thanks to Nathan_Sav, I manage to solve the problem. The real problem was that the user word is a reserved keyword, so we need to put the variable "user" between brackets *[]* so that the server recognizes it as an ordinary variable. I'm also changing the title of this post since it is misleading.

So, in conclusion, the result would be:

```
Public Function InsertPlayback(ByVal u As User, ByVal s As Song, plDate As Date) As Integer
    Return DBBroker.GetBroker.Change("INSERT INTO PLAYBACKS ([user], song, plDate) VALUES ('" & u.Email & "', " & s.idSong & ", '" & Date.Today.ToString & "');")
End Function
```

Comment: #'s instead of ' may do it.

Comment: I tried it, and it was exactly the same result. In Access goes well but executing the program goes wrong.

Comment: maybe `[user],song,...`

Comment: and/or `Date.Today.ToString()`

Comment: Ok, I've tried the `[user],song,...` and it worked. Thank you! I'll update the main post with the answer.

Comment: Cool.   You were using a sql reserved word i think.  Cheers